# Add a label in to a list that reads a file in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, file, addition

Hello i'm a new programmer and i have a project which i want the score to save in a list or array (which those 2 read my file with the usernames of the players) I have wrote that but i don't know why it doesn't write it

Here's my text file "name.txt":

```
Timmy1
Nick12
Mary3
```

And here's my code (label6 is the score):

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines("name.txt").ToList();

 void game(int x,string label)
        {
            label8.Text = label;
            randomImage = random.Next(1, x);
            pictureBox2.ImageLocation = "dice/" + randomImage.ToString() + ".png";
            int x1, y1;
            x1 = random.Next(panel1.Width - pictureBox2.Width);
            y1 = random.Next(panel1.Height - pictureBox2.Height);
            pictureBox2.Location = new Point(x1, y1);
            countDown--;

            label3.Text = countDown.ToString();
          
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++ ) {
                
                if (countDown == 0)
                {
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                    pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
                    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Play Again?", "Game Over!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                    { 
                        lines.Append(label6.Text);
                        Form4 f4 = new Form4(label2.Text, level);
                        this.Close();
                        f4.Show();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Form3 f3 = new Form3(label2.Text);
                        this.Hide();
                        f3.Show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I want the result of the text file name.txt be like that:

```
Timmy1
*Score of the player Timmy1*
Nick12
*Score of the player Nick12*
Mary3
*Score of the player Mary3*
```

Comment: You aren't writing the lines back to the file (assuming that's what you're trying to do). Hint: to write all lines to the file, there's a call very similar to `File.ReadAllLines()`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't write it, because you never told your program to do so.
You're reading a file and storing it's lines in a `List<string>`. Later on you add some values to this list but you never write your modified list to a file.

Somewhere in your code you have to call something like this:

```cs
File.WriteAllLines("name.txt", lines);
```